# Unable to mount location after installing Linux Mint

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, mount, linux-mint

I have been using Ubuntu for a while, but I decided to move to Linux Mint. I removed everything and clearly installed it. After the installation there are two parts which are `File System` and `Toshiba`. When I try to open Toshiba it says unable to mount location. Output of `sudo fdisk -l` can be seen below. Moreover I shared two pics to be more clear:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 750.2 GB, 750156374016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 91201 cylinders, total 1465149168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x8cecb72c

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048  1435547647   717772800   83  Linux
/dev/sda2      1435547648  1465147391    14799872   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

[image]
[image]

EDIT: I thought that providing more information will be useful.

1) I had created two partitions before I installed Linux Mint which are the `File System` and `swap` area and both of them are set as primary.

2) When I open Home screen this `Toshiba` icon does not shown on left tab like `File System` does, so there is no problem about that.

I can provide any information you want from me.